# Look up from different dataframes depending on a column

Tags: r

Supposing I have the following dataframes:

```
d1 <- data.frame(index = c(1,2,3,4), location = c('barn', 'house', 'restaurant', 'tomb'), random = c(5,3,2,1), different_col1 = c(66,33,22,11))
d2 <- data.frame(index = c(1,2,3,4), location = c('server', 'computer', 'home', 'dictionary'), random = c(1,7,2,9), differen_col2 = c('hi', 'there', 'different', 'column'))
```

What I am trying to do is get the location based on the index and what dataframe it is. So I have the following:

`data <- data.frame(src = c('one', 'one', 'two', 'one', 'two'), index = c(1,4,2,3,2))`

Where `src` indicates which dataframe the data should come from and `index`, the value in `index` from the `index` column.

```
src  |  index
-------------
one  |    1
one  |    4
two  |    2
one  |    3
two  |    2
```

And I would like it to become:

```
src  | index | location
-----------------------
one  |   1   | barn
one  |   4   | tomb
two  |   2   | computer
one  |   3   | restaurant
two  |   2   | computer
```

Due to the size of my data I would like to avoid `merge` or comparable joins (`sqldf`, etc).

Comment: I dont want to merge the two dataframes because of their sheer size. The way I would go about it is perhaps creating a blank column and filling it with d1 values first and d2 values second. I was wondering if there was a better way.

Comment: @Cenoc Ah, I see. I wish you had mentioned that before I created the solution with `merge` ;). Unfortunately, the method you describe in the comment above would overwrite everything in that column with the `d2` values. However I can add another solution without merge. Though personally I use merge on up on 8 million rows in some of my production scripts.

Comment: Be more specific about your data - "sheer size"?

Comment: The actual datasets end up being around 24GB in memory. d1 and d2 in my case are different enough where merging them doesn't make sense, and large enough where merging just the portions of interest takes up a decent chunk of memory.

Comment: wow if it's 24GB you might not even want to use R for this. Perhaps a relational DB, Java, or etc. Nevertheless I will see if I can give you a solution without `merge`. Please comment if you downvote it.

Comment: Then please update your example data to reflect dummy version of real data, as you mentioned they have different structure. Why not keep them in the database and access with sqldf?

Comment: I am using sqldf, the actual data sources are two separate file sets that are both >1TB, this is a select subset of both. I could use chunking, but I would rather not... I was wondering if there was a more elegant solution - I will update in order to reflect their different structure.

Comment: OK, so (someone please correct me if I'm wrong, but) I think you can't get around doing a join because the tables are of different lengths. So even if you order the index columns in all objects, you still need to join them. You can join with `merge`, with `sqldf`, with `data.table`, or other things, but you gotta join somehow. `data.table` is probably the fastest way with Big Data. Would that be an acceptable solution?

Comment: @Cenoc regarding that update you just made to the post -- you commented that adding that column is why you can't merge... that actually is not a problem for merging. So, to be clear, the reason you don't want to merge (or otherwise join) is the **size** of the data, right? Not anything to do that those extra columns, because I can show you how to handle those with a merge.

Comment: It's the size - the reason I bring up the extra columns is that it prevents me from just merging d1 and d2 outright, as I would like to keep the extra columns in memory, but I can see how I might have to end up sacrificing that. Thanks for all your help, this has definitely been edifying.

Comment: `ifelse(data$src=="one", d1$location[match(data$index, d1$index)], d2$location[match(data$index, d2$index)])` (without merge but no idea how efficient it is)

Comment: @Cenoc OK, check out my answer. I used `data.table` to speed up the merge and I show you how to handle the extra columns either by filling in their values or by ignoring them. You can also consolidate them into 1 column in the output table if you prefer (in which case you just give them the same name and treat them as character data).

Comment: sqldf does the merge outside R so size should not matter.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Here's one way to add a new column *by reference* using `data.table`:

```
require(data.table)
setDT(d1); setDT(d2); setDT(data) # convert all data.frames to data.tables

data[src == "one", location := d1[.SD, location, on="index"]]
data[src == "two", location := d2[.SD, location, on="index"]]
```

`.SD` stands for *subset of data*, and contains all columns in `data` that matches the condition provided in `i`-argument.

See the [vignettes](https://github.com/Rdatatable/data.table/wiki/Getting-started) for more.

You can use `match` in the expression to the right of `:=` as well instead of extracting `location` using a `join`. But it'd not be extensible if you'd want to match on multiple columns.

Comment: Great @arun. What does `:=` stands for and does here ? And what are `i` and `j` , is there a formula kinda way to represent this to help understand it better ?

Comment: @user5249203 it's better to refer to the `introduction to data.table` and `reference semantics` vignettes (that I've linked in the post). It shouldn't take a lot of time to go thro' them..

Answer (score 0):

```
library(dplyr)
mutate(data,
       location = ifelse(src == "one", 
                         as.character(d1[index, "location"]),
                         as.character(d2[index, "location"])))
```

output

```
  src index   location
1 one     1       barn
2 one     4       tomb
3 two     2   computer
4 one     3 restaurant
5 two     2   computer
```

Comment: Why was this answer downvoted ? Is it not the expected output?

Comment: Well, I guess the answer kicked Cenoc's butt

Comment: Its hard to understand what could have let people to down vote .

Comment: I guess it may be related to "lack of explanation" and "output". Yes, it is hard to interpret the code without explanation for someone who do not know of dplyr.

Answer (score 0):

`data.table` will help you to deal with Big Data much more efficiently.

You could either use `match` or a special data.table implementation of `merge` that's much faster than the merge of my original solution, as we discussed in the comments.

Here's an example:

```
require(data.table)
d1 <- data.frame(index = c(1,2,3,4), location = c('barn', 'house', 'restaurant', 'tomb'), random = c(5,3,2,1), different_col1 = c(66,33,22,11))
d2 <- data.frame(index = c(1,2,3,4), location = c('server', 'computer', 'home', 'dictionary'), random = c(1,7,2,9), differen_col2 = c('hi', 'there', 'different', 'column'))

mydata <- data.table(src = c('one', 'one', 'two', 'one', 'two'), index = c(1,4,2,3,2))

mydata.d1       <- mydata[mydata$src == "one",]
mydata.d2       <- mydata[mydata$src == "two",]

mydata.d1 <- merge(mydata.d1, d1, all.x = T, by = "index")
mydata.d2 <- merge(mydata.d2, d2, all.x = T, by = "index")

# If you want to keep the 'different column' values from d1 and d2:
mydata <- rbind(mydata.d1, mydata.d2, fill = T)
mydata

   index src   location random different_col1 differen_col2
1:     1 one       barn      5             66            NA
2:     3 one restaurant      2             22            NA
3:     4 one       tomb      1             11            NA
4:     2 two   computer      7             NA         there
5:     2 two   computer      7             NA         there

# If you don't want to keep those 'different column' values:
mydata <- rbind(mydata.d1[,.(index, src, location)], mydata.d2[,.(index, src, location)])

mydata

   index src   location
1:     1 one       barn
2:     3 one restaurant
3:     4 one       tomb
4:     2 two   computer
5:     2 two   computer
```

Answer (score -1):

Base solution: use a character index to chose the correct dataframe and then use `mapply` to handle submission of the multiple "parallel arguments.

```
 dput(dat)
structure(list(src = c("one", "one", "two", "one", "two"), X. = c("|", 
"|", "|", "|", "|"), index = c(1L, 4L, 2L, 3L, 2L), location = structure(c(1L, 
4L, 5L, 3L, 5L), .Label = c("barn", "house", "restaurant", "tomb", 
"computer", "dictionary", "home", "server"), class = "factor")), .Names = c("src", 
"X.", "index", "location"), row.names = c(NA, -5L), class = "data.frame")
```

May need to use stringsAsFactor to ensure character argument.

```
dat$location <- mapply(function(whichd,i) dlist[[whichd]][i,'location'], whichd=dat$src, i=dat$index)

> dat
  src X. index   location
1 one  |     1       barn
2 one  |     4       tomb
3 two  |     2   computer
4 one  |     3 restaurant
5 two  |     2   computer
>
```